# SWIPER JS - Centered Slides - Initial View: Left Slide Flush, Right Side Partially Visible Slide

Tags: javascript, slider

I am stuck on figuring out how to get Swiper.JS to use centered slides BUT on initial load the I would like the following:

The left side should be flush while the right side should have a partial slide visible.

After it has been swiped both the right and left sides should have partial slide visibility.

The closest thing I can find is the TV App on iOS Devices (see screenshots below).

#### Before swipe

[image: before swipe]

#### After swipe

[image: after swipe]

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trail and error this is what I came up with....

```
[1]: https://codepen.io/david2376/pen/rNmPNVO
```

If any one else comes up with a better solution, I would love to hear it.